# UIButton Image and background

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uibutton

Hello : please I have a UIButton with a specific image
when pressing the button I want to change another image the same size only different color

my question is what is the code to use thanks

Comment: Have you tried to do this by your self?? If YES then show the code, if NO then try it your self first..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIButton` has both a `image` and `backgroundImage`.  Set the `image` to the image you want when the button is not pressed, and the `backgroundImage` to what you want when the button is pressed.